# ASP.NET AJAX for Windows Server 2008 64 bit machine

Tags: asp.net

I have a web solution which uses ASP.NET AJAX Controls and has been running on Windows Server 2008 32 bit machine very well.

Now the server admins want to move this web to a new Windows Server 2008 64 bit machine, I was just wondering if ASP.NET AJAX is compatiable to this system, I can't seem to find anything about this issue by googling (Maybe I wasn't asking the right questions :)). Do I have to build the .dll's specifically for a 64 bit machine ? Is AJAX included for machines with .NET framework 3.0 installed (my solution is in .NET 3.0) ?

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have to build a special version for the 64-bit machine, that's the beauty of managed code as it isn't compiled for a specific platform until it is actually being run by the VM.

Also, AJAX 3.5 is included in .NET Framework 3.5, so you might want to install that.

[Here's a blog post covering this issue.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/30/asp-net-Ajax-in-net-3-5-and-vs-2008.aspx)